# How to change the default message text of OTP message sent by twilio verify

Tags: laravel, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am using Twillio API in my laravel application to send users an OTP, when they try to login through their mobile number. It is working fine, it is sending a message like "Your  verification code is XXXXXX".   My question is, is there any way so that I can customize the message text?? I want to greet my users when they try to login through the phone. I want to add the greeting line with the default line of verifying the message. Any suggestion is appreciable. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

By default you cannot customise the message. As Alan points out, the application name can be set as the service friendly name, which inserts the name in the message

> Your {Service Friendly Name} verification code is: {code}

But this does not allow you to directly customize the text on a per user basis.

There are [customization options](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/customization-options) available but you need to [talk to Twilio sales](https://www.twilio.com/help/sales) to enable them.

Comment: How to change the {service Friendly Name} in this message? Your {Service Friendly Name} verification code is: {code}. I want to customize this name.

Comment: By setting your [Verify service Friendly Name](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/service#update-a-service).

Answer (score 0):

Just the Verify Application/Service Name which is conveyed in the message.

`Friendly Name (used in the Verification message templates)`

Answer (score 0):

If You want message like this :

```
Your Grocery-store verification code is : ******
```

then change your verify service name from twilio console as Grocery-store